# How do I turn on mix-blend-mode only after I scroll past a certain point with pure css?

Tags: html, css

I figured out how to use mix-blend-mode with css but I am not sure how to only turn it on after a certain point I scroll through.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. CSS itself doesn't know where you are on a page at any given time, you'd need JavaScript for that. There's a pretty clean solution here using both CSS and JS which might be helpful https://css-tricks.com/styling-based-on-scroll-position/

Comment: Thanks, I'm kind of a beginner hehe